# JSON web token, make it client specific

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, token, jwt

I have generated token using Json Web Tokens. I use following parameters while generating token

```
  _tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // The signing key must match!
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
            ValidateActor=true,

            // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "TokenIssuer",

            // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "Audience",

            // Validate the token expiry
            ValidateLifetime = true,

            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,

        };
```

The issue is, the token can be used on any other computer and it will authorize the token as valid. I need to invalidate the token if generated from different client computer.

Comment: Token is generate from client?

Comment: No its generated by server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior makes sense. The token is generated with valid credentials and can be used from any computer until it expires.

That's the whole point of OAuth2. The token is not meant to be user specific, it's meant to be application specific.

If you still want to tie it to a specific computer then you could add something which identifies the originating computer, something like the IP address, hostname, mac address anything that can uniquely identifies the computer. You can add this information to the generated token itself and when the token is used you simply check to see if it matches the original data.

I am guessing you want to do this as a security measure but I still don't think that's how you should be using the system. The tokens are always safe as they are always passed in the authentication header which is encrypted over HTTPS .

You should always communicate with your authentication server over HTTPS to prevent any kind of tempering with the request and any kind of request interception.

Comment: IP address, hostname and mac address can all be spoofed/faked relatively easily.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : No.

Long answer :

What you are looking for is device attestation, the ability to identity a device and ensure only that device is communicating. This is a well known problem - it takes controlling the device at the OS level, ensuring the token cannot be stolen (via app exploits, device exploits, or communications exploits). It's next to impossible.

It's "even more impossible" in OAuth, because the server is generating the token, not the client. That's not what OAuth was designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem while using a jwt token in a HTTPS header request. If you want it such that the second device not be able to use the same token, I think you have to make a field in your DB that stores the MAC address of user devices, and if the same user and password send a request to the server with a different MAC address, you ensure that the user is not unauthorized.